# How to keep Pose Markers in RViz?

Tags: ros, rviz, markers.rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I publish a PoseStamped topic "pose" and display the pose in RViz using the display type "Pose" (with shape axes). However, I would like to keep the old poses in order to see the whole trajectory of rather than only the latest pose.

I know it is also possible to use visualization markers instead (is there a "axes" visualization marker type?) according to [wiki.ros.org/rviz/DisplayTypes/Marker](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/DisplayTypes/Marker) and use `marker.action = visualization_msgs::Marker::ADD;`.

But if this is possible directly in the RViz GUI, I would prefer this solution instead of implementing the markers.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213815/how-to-keep-pose-markers-in-rviz?/) by [takahashi](https://answers.ros.org/users/23199/takahashi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 185 on 2015-07-15

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2015-07-16**:
There was recently a pull request that was merged which may offer what you're looking for in the PoseArray display plugin: https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz/pull/858

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use a Pose Array

```
def talker():
    obj = get_poses()
    pub = rospy.Publisher('topic', PoseArray, queue_size=len(obj))
    rospy.init_node('pose_array')
    rate = rospy.Rate(60) # 10hz
    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        Poses = PoseArray()
        Poses.header.frame_id = "/surface"
        Poses.header.stamp = rospy.Time.now()
        for i in range(len(obj)):
            Poses.poses.append(obj[i])
        pub.publish(Poses)
        rate.sleep()
```

---

Originally posted by [swethmandava](https://answers.ros.org/users/26039/swethmandava/) with karma: 102 on 2016-04-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [takahashi](https://answers.ros.org/users/23199/takahashi/) on 2016-04-13**:
In this solution the full pose array is published everytime. This seems to generate a lot of overhead for large arrays (by repeatedly sending the full array) and I think it is much more efficient to have a pose visual that has an internal buffer, where the previous poses are stored.